# How detect all users connected to voiceChannel | Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i'm working on a `economy bot` and I need to know who is connect in all `voiceChannel` every `minutes`.
Let me explain, when someone send a message, he get 1 `coin`. with this coin he can buy `roles` and `emoji` acces.

**The user with more coins are the best !**

Now the `message economy` it's good ! they are no probleme but I would like to go *further* ! I would like to give 1 `coins` to **all** *users* connected in `voiceChannel` **every** *minutes*

To do that I know how to user `setInterval` but i don't know how i can find **all** *user*  `connect` in `voiceChannel`

That's why i'm ask you **solutions** and **help**. **Thanks !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the following every minute using [`client.setInterval()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=setInterval):

```js
client.setInterval(() => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(GUILD_ID);
    const voiceChannel = guild.channels.get(VC_ID);
    voiceChannel.members.forEach(member => {
        // Give users a coin
    })
}, 60000)
```

Comment: This is an example.... You need to provide your own IDs, you can get them by right-clicking the guild and channel and clicking `Copy ID`, you need to have developer mode enable though, here is a guide on how to enable it: https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-

Comment: Oh !  Another error : client.guilds.cache.get(...).channels.get is not a function

Comment: If an answer solves your issue, you should accept it to let others know it worked

Answer (score 0):

One you get the reference to the `VoiceChannel` object (with `const voiceChannel = guild.channels.get(VOICE_CHAN_ID)`, for example), you can list all the members with `voiceChannel.members`.

See [`VoiceChannel#members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members) and [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

Comment: Can you accept this answer if it solved your problem? Thanks.